# how to read full input signal with STFT in matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, sound, stft

Please help! I am trying to figure out why in the code i have below my input signal is being cropped but in the code I have a full signal created. The white noise created is 5000 samples for the right channel with the left channel silent then a 10000 pause sample and then 5000 samples for the left with the right channel silent. When i run it through my STFT  function is when it is being cropped and throwing me off on trying to do the spectrogram of signal before the STFT and after.

```
function newwhitenoise()
L = 5000; %Sample length for the random signal
Pause = 10000; %Sample Pause Gap
mu = 0;
sigma = 2;

%Need to see left signal is not displaying
Left_signal = sigma*randn(L,1) + mu;
Right_signal = sigma*randn(L,1) + mu;

Long_signal = [Left_signal zeros(L,1); zeros(Pause,2); zeros(L,1) Right_signal];

%Player Object
soundRecord(Long_signal);


disp([Left_signal zeros(L,1)]);
%sound(Long_signal, Fs);

%Plots subplots in graph
%figure
%subplot(211);
%plot(Left_signal, 'b'); grid on;
%subplot(212);
%plot(Right_signal, 'r'); grid on;
end

function signalplayer(signal)
    %load(signal);
    fs = 44100; %Sample Frequency
    obj = audioplayer(signal,fs);
    play(obj);
end

function soundRecord (signal)
fs = 44100; %Sample Frequency
recObj = audiorecorder(44100, 16, 2);
get(recObj)

%save sound to wave file
%filename = 'location.flac';
audiowrite('input.wav',signal, fs);


if ~exist('inFile')
    inFile = 'input.wav';
end

if ~exist('outFile')
    outFile = 'output.wav';
end

if ~exist('frameWidth')
    frameWidth = 4096;          % size of FFT frame, better be a power of 2
end
frameHop = frameWidth/2;

analWindow = hanning(frameWidth);

[inBuffer, Fs] = wavread(inFile);

x = [inBuffer(:,1); linspace(0, 0, frameWidth)'];                   % use left channel only, zeropad one frame at the end

clear inBuffer;

numSamples = length(x);

numFrames = floor(numSamples/frameHop)-1;

% disp(frameWidth);
% disp(numSamples);
% disp(frameHop);
% disp(numFrames);
% disp(size(analWindow));
% disp(size(transpose(analWindow)));

y = linspace(0, 0, numSamples)';


n = 0;                              % init sample pointer.  unlike MATLAB, i like counting from 0

for frameIndex = 1:numFrames

     xWindowed = x(n+1:n+frameWidth) .* analWindow;     % get and window the input audio frame

     X = fft(fftshift(xWindowed));              % do the FFT

     Y = X;                         % copy the input spectrum to output

                                % do whatever processing to Y that you like

     yWindowed = fftshift(real(ifft(Y)));           % convert back to time domain, toss the imaginary part
 %disp(size(x(1:frameWidth)));
 %disp(size(yWindowed));

     y(n+1:n+frameWidth) = y(n+1:n+frameWidth) + yWindowed;

     n = n + frameHop;


end

spectrogram(y,256,250,256,fs,'yaxis')
 title 'Spectra using Short-time Fourier Transform'

wavwrite(y, Fs, 'output.wav');
```

Comment: Please trim all the unnecessary parts of your code. I doubt anyone is going to read through the entire thing trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, i recognize some of my code (that i grabbed from an old file and trimmed just to show how you can window and overlap-add frames of audio, and how you can DFT and inverse DFT the windowed segments).  a couple things, `wavread()` and `wavwrite()` are being deprecated in favor of `audioread()` and `audiowrite()`.  also `exist()` has changed slightly since the olden days.  `if ~exist('myVariableName')` should probabably be changed to `if ~exist('myVariableName', 'var')`.

that said, what should come out on `y` should be the same as what goes into `x` with the exception of the first half-frame (which is 2048 samples long) and the last half-frame will have the Hann (called "`hanning()`" in MATLAB, i hate that) window applied and will not be overlap adding with any other frames.  but in-between `y(2048)` and `y(numSamples-2048)` should be the same as `x(..)`.  you need to verify that such is the case.  that's a significant portion of `long_Signal`.  it might not be long enough for you to not care about the edge effects.

just for shits and grins, you could make plot a 3D plot of the magnitude of the spectra of all of the `xWindowed` (or of `yWindowed`) frames and compare the looks of it to what comes outa `spectrogram(..)`.  they should look similar except for the different painting schemes the two plots would have.

Comment: I messed around with the pwelch function and it still not coming out right.I need the window size at 32 samples and was trying to make the horizontal axis frequency and vertical axis amplitude.

Comment: well, i have never used the `pwelch()` function and am not disposed toward figuring it out.  the code that i presented is a straight-forward application of windowing and overlap-adding.  and if you do nothing to the windowed segments (and doing `fft(fftshift())` followed by `fftshift(ifft())` is doing nothing), then what gets overlapped and added should come out to be the same as what goes in.  if you do something in between the FFT and iFFT, that is what the STFT is all about.  and you can make the `frameWidth` as short as you want, but i would keep it a power of 2.

Comment: oh ok so i can just graph the ending up the code that you had and it should give me what I am looking for @robert bristow-johnson because all I looking for is the spectra of the signal in graph form after it goes through the STFT

Comment: fine, so after the `fft(fftshift())`, then plot it.  or maybe plot it with `semilogx(20*log10(abs(...)))` if you like a dB vs. log-frequency plot (like a bode plot).  or you can put the FFT output of each frame into one column of a 2-dimensional array and plot the 2-dim array, maybe with `surf()`.

Comment: one more question @robert bristow-johnson how do i apply the STFT for both channels because I know it has to do one channel at a time but trying to see how to apply it to both channels instead of just one like your code does

Comment: do you want a single spectral plot or a pair of them?  if the former, i dunno, maybe add the two channels together.  do you want to input a two-channel soundfile into MATLAB instead of throwing one away, like i did?

Comment: yes I want to keep the two-channel signal i had before the fft and keep both after the FFT and not throw one away. I had a pause also that was part of the sound and I want to keep that too.

Comment: yes that is what im looking for @robert bristow-johnson

Comment: oh yea and i am trying to keep both files for the output as well after the fft so when it writes to the wav file its not just one channel I still need both channels and the pause together @robert bristow-johnson

Comment: hey dude.  i just can't do this anymore.  you're gonna have to dink around with it and figure it out.  `inBuffer(:,1)` is where i was yanking just the left channel of a possibly multichannel soundfile.  you're gonna have to use the `size()` utility to figure out how many samples and how many channels you got.  experiment!  you'll eventually stumble across it.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: catch my +1 for your effort and **patience** ;)